# Schnorr-signature calculating a coefficient

Tags: signature, schnorr-signature

I need to create program that makes signature for selected file. I simplified algorithm a little, because I draw max `64 bit` prime numbers instead of `512 bit` - like its recommended in Applied Cryptography book.

I have already drew private key which is for example: $1848661337$, and now I need to calculate public key. I need to choose an $a \not = 1$, such that $a^q = 1 \bmod p$, where $q$ and $p$ are prime numbers. 
I have tried a lot of examples and it seems that the second part of this expression always is going to be $1$? If it is true, $a$ must be $1$?

I thought in the book is mistake but, I found other resources that confirm version from book.

I cant handle it. What should I do to solve this problem?

Numbers from trial:

- $a^{1034069683} = 1 \bmod 3465190093$
- $a^{45900161} = 1 \bmod 95899459$
- $a^{200001283} = 1 \bmod 490810459$
- $a^{390810929} = 1 \bmod 890811619$

Comment: @kelalaka Done. As You can see, 1 mod x is always 1.

Comment: Hint: for 1) the mod prime, power is prime and gcd(power,mod−1)=1, then $a$ must be?

Comment: Hint: what you want is parameters for a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group). You need to choose $p$
and $q$ together, since $q$ must divide $p-1$.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to calculate the group generator. I followed the steps from source:

`p = qr + 1

917794499 = 917794489*r + 1

p/q - 1/q = r

917794499/917794489 - 1/917794489 = r

r = 1.00000000981


h is any number gt then 1, so lets say its 2 in this example

g = h^r mod p

g = 2^1.00000000981 mod 917794499

g = 2.0000000136`

Comment: @kelalaka Next hint please :/

Comment: What is your $p$ and $q$. You need to find a prime $p= q r + 1$ where $q$ also a prime and $r$ is an integer, too.  So first generate prime $q$ and check for the primeness of $r q+1$ for $r \in \{2,3,\ldots\}$. Then using $r$ you search for an $h$